# Selected user account does not exist in tenant 'UserVoice, Inc.'

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-account, azure-sphere

I'm trying to login and vote on https://feedback.azure.com/forums/915433-azure-sphere/suggestions/36196912-allow-for-transfering-device-ownership

While using my personal microsoft account, it says "Selected user account does not exist in tenant 'UserVoice, Inc.' and cannot access the application '91a42e81-999b-4cf1-aa36-bb33f25ff53b' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. "

As I understand, it's a problem on UserVoice tenant and i have no access to it to add my email as guest user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to login with a **Azure Active Directory user account**, personal account is not allowed here.

The login endpoint is `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=91a42e81-999b-4cf1-aa36-bb33f25ff53b&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ffeedback.azure.com%2Fauth%2Foidc%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=openid+email+profile+offline_access&state=98a2f664a4ff12e695a7d482dbf1f6a07a0901f95171d70f6cb779639b71e979&sso_reload=true`

It is a multi-tenant application with v1.0 endpoint. So you can login with any Azure Active Directory tenant users. Only v2.0 endpoint supports personal accounts.

Comment: 2021 update - still cant use personal microsoft account via SSO... i can login local  with my gmail address though?!

Answer (score 0):

Azure Sphere does now [support signing in with a personal account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-sphere/resources/rbac-device-migration). (Though it did not at the time the questions was asked, and the first answer was given.)

Comment: this question about signing with personal account to feedback portal, not Azure Sphere.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Multitenant stuff you need to use following endpoints.

Login url: https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

Token Url:

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token'](https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token%27),