# How do I add an initial User to a new Tenant in the Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, active-directory

I am trying to set up a new Web Application in Visual Studio using Microsoft authentication.

I have created a new Tenant in portal.azure.com. My issue is, every page I visit in the Azure Portal, including my profile, I receive a 403 error.
The only function I am able to perform is creating a new App Registration.

When I try to authentication in the Web Application, I receive the error "Selected user account does not exist in tenant".
I am confused with how to add the account that created the Tenant to it without the required permissions.

Does anybody know how I can go about resolving this issue?
TIA.

[image: Azure Portal error]

[image: Web Application authentication error]

Comment: If you [create the new tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-access-create-new-tenant) correctly and switch your account to this tenant?

Answer (score 0):

Error means that  the logged in email address you are trying to use to link to is not yet added to  your new tenant. Please make sure that the work email address is added in that tenant, if it is not admin.

- If you have added the account to tenant or you are the admin itself , please refresh and try again.
- Sign out and clear all cookies .
- Try using a Microsoft Edge "InPrivate"/ Incognito browser and check if you are signing into correct tenant and switch  the tenant and try to access the app.
- If you have the same account with matching your personal account ,try to change it and add as  Microsoft account .
- Try to login with common endpoint https://login.microsoftonline.com/common, if it is personal account and app is multitenant.

If above doesn’t solve the issue see [This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-code-aadsts50020-user-account-identity-provider-does-not-exist) which lists several causes to find yours.

**References:**

1. [azure active directory - Selected user account does not exist in tenant 'UserVoice, Inc.' - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58133841/selected-user-account-does-not-exist-in-tenant-uservoice-inc)
2. [azure - Microsoft Graph Identity Java - Selected user account does not exist in tenant 'Microsoft Services' - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61674188/microsoft-graph-identity-java-selected-user-account-does-not-exist-in-tenant)